# string indices must be integers but format is a dictionary, type is a list

Tags: python

I have this file I would like to iterate over as a dictionary, extracting the doc ID, but it does not work, seemingly it is a list...I have tried many things. I do have the file in json format already as well as text, here I have used the text file. I just want to extract the doc ID.

```
['[{"doc_id":"C00001","LIWC_WC":4051,"LIWC_Analytic":88.89,"LIWC_Clout":76.97,"LIWC_Authentic":13.98,"LIWC_Tone":5.22,"LIWC_WPS":22.26,"LIWC_Sixltr":27.18,"LIWC_Dic":79.26,"LIWC_function":46.63,"LIWC_pronoun":9.78,"LIWC_ppron":4.2,"LIWC_i":0.17,"LIWC_we":0.42,"LIWC_you":0.02,"LIWC_shehe":2.42,"LIWC_they":1.16,"LIWC_ipron":5.58,"LIWC_article":6.96,"LIWC_prep":15.77,"LIWC_auxverb":6.81,"LIWC_adverb":3.33,"LIWC_conj":6.07,"LIWC_negate":0.59,"LIWC_verb":10.54,"LIWC_adj":4.32,"LIWC_compare":2.72,"LIWC_interrog":
```

```
for d in data:
    print (d['doc_id'])
```

```
for d in data:
    for key in d:
        print (d[key])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-57622719c3c4> in <module>
      1 for d in data:
----> 2     print (d['doc_id'])
      3 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `d` is a string. You need to load it via `json.loads`.

Comment: You have a list containing a string that represents a Python object. So you need to first take the string out of the list and then parse the string. Then you will get a list that contains a dictionary, whose `'doc_id'` key you can access.

Comment: @mkrieger1 does this mean extracting the entire file from the list and then parsing that? the file is about 500mb

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/16836078

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes indeed it is a json file, as I have a copy of it in .json format, anyways, I am not able to convert it using json.loads...

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the unclosed the brackets and curly braces your JSON is valid

```
import json
dictList = ['[{"doc_id":"C00001","LIWC_WC":4051,"LIWC_Analytic":88.89,"LIWC_Clout":76.97,"LIWC_Authentic":13.98,"LIWC_Tone":5.22,"LIWC_WPS":22.26,"LIWC_Sixltr":27.18,"LIWC_Dic":79.26,"LIWC_function":46.63,"LIWC_pronoun":9.78,"LIWC_ppron":4.2,"LIWC_i":0.17,"LIWC_we":0.42,"LIWC_you":0.02,"LIWC_shehe":2.42,"LIWC_they":1.16,"LIWC_ipron":5.58,"LIWC_article":6.96,"LIWC_prep":15.77,"LIWC_auxverb":6.81,"LIWC_adverb":3.33,"LIWC_conj":6.07,"LIWC_negate":0.59,"LIWC_verb":10.54,"LIWC_adj":4.32,"LIWC_compare":2.72}]']
for data in dictList:
    x = json.loads(data)
for dict in x:
    print(dict['doc_id'])
```

**Output**

```
C00001
```

To print all the keys in the dictionary

```
import json
dictList = ['[{"doc_id":"C00001","LIWC_WC":4051,"LIWC_Analytic":88.89,"LIWC_Clout":76.97,"LIWC_Authentic":13.98,"LIWC_Tone":5.22,"LIWC_WPS":22.26,"LIWC_Sixltr":27.18,"LIWC_Dic":79.26,"LIWC_function":46.63,"LIWC_pronoun":9.78,"LIWC_ppron":4.2,"LIWC_i":0.17,"LIWC_we":0.42,"LIWC_you":0.02,"LIWC_shehe":2.42,"LIWC_they":1.16,"LIWC_ipron":5.58,"LIWC_article":6.96,"LIWC_prep":15.77,"LIWC_auxverb":6.81,"LIWC_adverb":3.33,"LIWC_conj":6.07,"LIWC_negate":0.59,"LIWC_verb":10.54,"LIWC_adj":4.32,"LIWC_compare":2.72}]']
for data in dictList:
    x = json.loads(data)
for dict in x:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        print(key)
```

Comment: How did you addd quotes on each?

Comment: I did that manually

Comment: Ah okay, I couldn't as its almost 1 million rows

Comment: Oh ok I don’t think the data is in json format

Comment: Yes, I have two files, one with format json, one with text... it is from this website: https://osf.io/snpcg/

Comment: Is the file LOCO.json?

Comment: Its LOCO_lfs.json... I just checked it now with a head, and it seems the same honestly. there are still no double quotes around each value. hmph.

Comment: Hmm ok, I am downloading the huge file

Comment: Okay, what are you using to download? just out of curiosity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242989/discussion-between-rohith-nambiar-and-francesca-c).

Comment: Wonderful, it worked perfect!

Comment: If I want to just print the keys itself?

Comment: You mean you want to print all the keys?

Comment: I guess, yes, or is there a better way to access them, in your opinion through iteration, rather than printing all? eg: print only the keys that have the highest score (value) (there are two types of keys: LIWC and Empath) so ideally printing both kinds of keys but the top for those two types

Comment: Do you mean printing only the key that contains the highest value or printing the keys in descending order based on value? I did not quite understand your second query regarding the two types of keys

Answer (score 1):

SuperStormer is right.

```py
import json
data = json.loads('[{"doc_id":"C00001","LIWC_WC":4051,"LIWC_Analytic":88.89,"LIWC_Clout":76.97,"LIWC_Authentic":13.98,"LIWC_Tone":5.22,"LIWC_WPS":22.26,"LIWC_Sixltr":27.18,"LIWC_Dic":79.26,"LIWC_function":46.63,"LIWC_pronoun":9.78,"LIWC_ppron":4.2,"LIWC_i":0.17,"LIWC_we":0.42,"LIWC_you":0.02,"LIWC_shehe":2.42,"LIWC_they":1.16,"LIWC_ipron":5.58,"LIWC_article":6.96,"LIWC_prep":15.77,"LIWC_auxverb":6.81,"LIWC_adverb":3.33,"LIWC_conj":6.07,"LIWC_negate":0.59,"LIWC_verb":10.54,"LIWC_adj":4.32,"LIWC_compare":2.72}]')
```

Now `data` is a list that only contains a dict. You should probably also remove the brackets because this doesn't seem to need to be a list, based on what you copied in from the file.
`json` module is essential to convert these strings into more useful datatypes.

Comment: I know I cut a little bit at the end, because I don't know exactly what the file is and what is in it, but it should work if you use the complete contents of whatever file you have

Comment: Okay, yes I tried this before as well.. I get "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list" let me remove the brackets then..

Comment: I tried to remove the brackets, with "!sed '1s/^.//' liwc_emp.txt > liwc_empv2.txt" and it left me with "['{"doc_id":"C00001" " if I add another '.' it removes the curly bracket... this input is still a list of strings.. should I manually remove it?